# Check if a file is a .tsv file

Tags: python, testing, spreadsheet

This question is closely related to [this thread](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/61996/github-continuous-integration-to-validate-a-csv-tsv-file). I would like to set up a function that checks if an input file is a `.tsv` file. I realized that it's not sufficient to only use `file.endswith('.tsv')` as you can easily just save a comma-separated or semicolon-separated file with the `.tsv` ending.

Consider the following table:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | foo |
| 3.42 | bar | foo, bar |

In a text editor this would look something like this:

[image]

And from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) we know that:

> Records are separated by newlines, and values within a record are
> separated by tab characters.

So I think the MVP would be to check that each line ends with a newline character and that each line contains the same amount of tab-characters? I am not sure though if this is correct and/or sufficient and/or if I maybe have overseen other things that one needs to check for.

Comment: Lines always end with newline characters and tsv lines don't always contain the same number of tab characters.

Comment: How about attempting to use the `csv` package to open the file using a tab delimiter specification. See if it parses at all and maybe if it does inspect some of the rows to see if they make sense. I would definitely try to leverage someone else's work on CSV parsing as I am lead to believe it is non-trivial.

Comment: There is no test; "is this TSV?" is not a falsifiable premise. `I am a string` is valid as TSV file contents -- only one cell, and only one row, but a TSV file nonetheless; same for `1,2` (sure, if it _were_ a CSV it would have two columns, but it could be a TSV with only one column). Similarly, binary content and a ZIP file footer being present in a TSV cell is improbable, but can't be disproved. You can readily enough conclude that something isn't _likely_ to be a TSV file, but you cannot prove that it _isn't_ one.

Answer (score 3):

How about attempting to parse the file with the `CSV` package and see how many columns you get. If it is an expected number then you probably have a tsv file. If the number of columns is unexpected, particularly if it is 1 then you probably don't have a tsv file. You can determine if a 1 column file is a valid tsv or not for your use case.

You might expand this and sample a number of rows to see if they show valid results. For example is column 3 always an int...

```py
import csv

for filename in ["in.csv", "in.tsv", ""]:
    try:
        with open(filename, "r", newline="") as file_in:
            reader = csv.reader(file_in, delimiter="\t")
            headers = next(reader)

            column_count = len(headers)
            if column_count == 1:
                raise ValueError("Column Count is 1")
            
            ## -------------------
            ## inspect some of the rows?
            ## -------------------
            ## for row in reader:
            ##     ....
            ## -------------------

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"file \"{filename}\" is probably not a tsv")
        # print(e)
        continue

    print(f"file \"{filename}\" appears to have {column_count} columns")
```

With some mocked data I get:

```
file "in.csv" is probably not a tsv
file "in.tsv" appears to have 3 columns
file "" is probably not a tsv
```

Comment: This is a good solution because you won't have any mismatches in the code to check/read. in general, checking if it is a parsable DFA is the same level of complexity as actually parsing.

Comment: Most file systems don't allow an empty filename.  When reading CSV files the `csv` module strongly suggests opening with `newline=""` option and when opening in text mode explicitly giving the encoding might be a good idea.  The `continue` is superfluous, this would happen anyway.  With an empty file the `next()` call raises an Exception.

Comment: The `continue` is required to prevent the final `print()` for a given file in the event that it is not valid. It is required for the solution to work correctly. The file should probably be opened with the newline though and I'll make that update. The empty filename illustrates an example of an exception while reading that is handled by the existing code